# Bitdefender license

Tags: security, anti-virus, license, bitdefender

I have bought Bitdefender Internet Security 2015 and it is shipped with a license to install it on 3 PCs. I only have 2 PCs: A laptop and a desktop computer, so my question is: Can I give away the 3rd license to a friend?

Comment: @Dave That is wrong. The EULA specifically states that it is non-transferable.

Comment: @MichaelFrank, good spot, +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not transferable. The EULA states the following:

> "Bitdefender hereby grants you and only you the following non-exclusive, limited, non assignable, non-transferable, non-sublicensable and royalty-bearing license to use Bitdefender Product."

also:

> "GRANT OF LICENSE. Bitdefender Product is protected by copyright laws and international copyright treaties, as well as other intellectual property laws and treaties. **Bitdefender Product is licensed, not sold.** This agreement only gives You some rights to use Bitdefender Product. Bitdefender reserves all other rights. Unless applicable law gives you more rights despite this limitation, You may use Bitdefender Product only as expressly permitted in this Agreement."

Bold is my emphasis. As it is licensed to only you, you do not have the right to give it away as it is not your product to give.

http://www.bitdefender.com/site/view/eula.html